# How to add Advanced Placeholder fields in esingatures.io template

Tags: e-signature

I have a requirement where I have to prepare a single file from multiple files and bundle that to a single field.

I have gone through the documentation of esingatures.io and found there are Advanced Placeholder fields are there and under that we have type as template and template id from the existing templates listed on esignatures.io.

But I didn't find any example how we can prepare the master template and add advanced placeholder fields in that.

If anyone have idea on this please help me on this.

Thanks